# Selecting row if they are before a particular date

Tags: c#, date

How can I alter the following foreach statement to only pick up rows if they are before or on a particular date (`odDate`). Currently they only pick up dates if they match.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), odDate, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
       row.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
       row.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Note that `row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` and `odDate` are both strings in the format **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**.

Comment: Can you change the query that populates your dataset to filter records you don't want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of working with strings you should work with datetime instances.

```
DateTime dateBase = DateTime.Parse(odDate);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DateTime dateRow = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    row.Visible = (dateRow >= dateBase);
}
```

It is not clear if you want the grid rows visible if they precede the base date or not.
However switching the condition will fix the code above.